# QTreeView does only update when Cursor is moved

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtreeview

I'm using a QTreeView to display data that is updated every second. Each Item in the View has a setData(QVariant value)-function that emit's a custom dataChanged(int index, QVariant value)-signal. When the items are inserted to the Model, the dataChanged()-Signal of the Item get's connected to a itemDataChanged()-Slot of the Model. This function calls the dataChanged()-Signal of the QAbstractItemModel.

When I now start the application, the QTreeView get's only updated when I move my Cursor over the QTreeView.

I already found someone else having the problem, but without a solution. Below are links, to a video of the effect and the original post from qtcentre.org.

http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/55490-QTreeView-unexpectedly-updates-on-mouse-movement-%28Win-Linux%29-or-focus-change-%28OSX%29

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rVhB60VqBQ&feature=youtu.be

Comment: Are you using a QAbstractItemModel descendant as model ?

Comment: Yes I inherited it from QAbstractItemModel

Comment: Did you call this before inserting ? http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows

Comment: I use beginResetModel() and endResetModel() instead. I think it has the same effect. Am I right?

Comment: Yes it should work exactly the same way, so I do not have other ideas to suggest

Comment: Do you have some code to test the problem?

Comment: I also have this problem.